# How to set node creation limit by user type in Drupal

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm trying to set the limit on authenticated user for creating particular type of content(adding user limit on content type).

[Node limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_limit) module has same functionality in Drupal 7 but i'm looking for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 1):

Another new module for Drupal 8: https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_limit

Some details about it, from its project page:

> Entity Limit allows administrators to restrict the creation of the number of entities that users may create. Basically, this module provides options to define a creation limit based on user and role.

Answer (score 0):

[entity limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_limit) module should have what you need.

> Currently, entity_limit offers the following functionalities
>
> 1. Per User entity limit settings.
> 2. Per Role entity limit settings.
> 3. Priority based entity limit configurations.

But you can also try node limit has a Drupal 8 dev version .